# Javascript in Delphi TWebBrowser, Closing Threads

Tags: javascript, delphi, google-maps, twebbrowser, iwebbrowser2

I am attempting to build a system in delphi that allows users to use Google Maps. It all works fine, but i'm noticing that every time a new TWebBrowser object is created and the javascript that handles Google Maps is loaded, a number of new Threads is generated.

My problem is that even once the webbrowser is destroyed (and it is definately destroyed) the created threads persist. I'm designing this program to have long running times and the opening and closing of google maps to happen many times and as such, after a while, so many threads have been generated and not terminated that the program slows down dramatically.

Is there any way to Destroy these threads myself, or am I doing something wrong which is causing the threads to persist?

I am basing my program off of the following code:

```
const
HTMLStr: AnsiString =
'<html> '+    
'<head> '+
'<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" /> '+
'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">        </script> '+
'<script type="text/javascript"> '+
''+
''+
'  var geocoder; '+
'  var map;  '+
'  var trafficLayer;'+
'  var bikeLayer;'+
'  var markersArray = [];'+
''+
''+
'  function initialize() { '+
'    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();'+
'    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.714776,-74.019213); '+
'    var myOptions = { '+
'      zoom: 13, '+
'      center: latlng, '+
'      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP '+
'    }; '+
'    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); '+
'    trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();'+
'    bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();'+
'    map.set("streetViewControl", false);'+
'  } '+
''+
''+
'  function codeAddress(address) { '+
'    if (geocoder) {'+
'      geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) { '+
'        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {'+
'          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);'+
'          PutMarker(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),     results[0].geometry.location.lng(),     results[0].geometry.location.lat()+","+results[0].geometry.location.lng());'+
'        } else {'+
'          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);'+
'        }'+
'      });'+
'    }'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lang) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   map.setCenter(latlng);'+
'   PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Lat+","+Lang);'+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'function ClearMarkers() {  '+
'  if (markersArray) {        '+
'    for (i in markersArray) {  '+
'      markersArray[i].setMap(null); '+
'    } '+
'  } '+
'}  '+
''+
'  function PutMarker(Lat, Lang, Msg) { '+
'   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lang);'+
'   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'+
'      position: latlng, '+
'      map: map,'+
'      title: Msg+" ("+Lat+","+Lang+")"'+
'  });'+
' markersArray.push(marker); '+
'  }'+
''+
''+
'  function TrafficOn()   { trafficLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function TrafficOff()  { trafficLayer.setMap(null); }'+
''+''+
'  function BicyclingOn() { bikeLayer.setMap(map); }'+
''+
'  function BicyclingOff(){ bikeLayer.setMap(null);}'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOn() { map.set("streetViewControl", true); }'+
''+
'  function StreetViewOff() { map.set("streetViewControl", false); }'+
''+
''+'</script> '+
'</head> '+
'<body onload="initialize()"> '+
'  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div> '+
'</body> '+
'</html> ';


procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  aStream     : TMemoryStream;
begin
   WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
    if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
    begin
      aStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
     aStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(HTMLStr)^, Length(HTMLStr));
     //aStream.Write(HTMLStr[1], Length(HTMLStr));
     aStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
     (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(aStream));
  finally
     aStream.Free;
  end;
  HTMLWindow2 := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;

end;
end;


procedure TfrmMain.ButtonGotoLocationClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('GotoLatLng(%s,%s)',[Latitude.Text,Longitude.Text]),         'JavaScript');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ButtonClearMarkersClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HTMLWindow2.execScript('ClearMarkers()', 'JavaScript')
end;

procedure TfrmMain.ButtonGotoAddressClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   address    : string;
begin
   address := MemoAddress.Lines.Text;
   address := StringReplace(StringReplace(Trim(address), #13, ' ', [rfReplaceAll]), #10, ' '    , [rfReplaceAll]);
   HTMLWindow2.execScript(Format('codeAddress(%s)',[QuotedStr(address)]),     'JavaScript');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.CheckBoxStreeViewClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if CheckBoxStreeView.Checked then
     HTMLWindow2.execScript('StreetViewOn()', 'JavaScript')
    else
     HTMLWindow2.execScript('StreetViewOff()', 'JavaScript');

end;

procedure TfrmMain.CheckBoxBicyclingClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if CheckBoxBicycling.Checked then
     HTMLWindow2.execScript('BicyclingOn()', 'JavaScript')
    else
     HTMLWindow2.execScript('BicyclingOff()', 'JavaScript');
 end;


procedure TfrmMain.CheckBoxTrafficClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if CheckBoxTraffic.Checked then
     HTMLWindow2.execScript('TrafficOn()', 'JavaScript')
    else
     HTMLWindow2.execScript('TrafficOff()', 'JavaScript');
 end;


end.
```

Program uses a basic destructor that sets the HTMLWindow to navigate to about:blank.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where and how do you destroy the webbrowser?

Comment: The Webbrowser sits on a TForm that is handled by a parent TForm, I destroy the Child TForm and use the following destructor code:
`destructor TGoogleMap.Destroy;
begin
  HTMLWindow2.navigate('about:blank');
  HTMLWindow2 := nil;
  WebBrowser1.DestroyComponents;
  WebBrowser1.Destroy;

  inherited
end;`

Comment: For start, Your `destructor` is not needed at all. your are doing a big salad there. the owner form will free the `TWebBrowser` itself.

Comment: ^^  +1   +  Destroying an object is done by calling the Free Method, not Destroy...

Comment: @whosrdaddy: `Destroy()` is the actual destructor, and it can be called directly. `Free()` is merely a wrapper that calls `Destroy()` only if the `Self` pointer is not `nil`.

Comment: `Destroy` can be called directly, though it is often advised never to do so. But then again, to free a modal, you shouldn't call `Free` either, but rather call `Release`, which sends a message to the form telling it it should free itself. If you don't do this, controls on the form may still try to interact with the form that is already destroyed. But I doubt that's the problem here.

Comment: By the way, if the constructor fails (raises an exception for whatever reason), the destructor is still called. Every object that would have been created after the exception in the constructor will still be 'nil', causing the destructor to fail again if you call `Destroy` instead of `Free`, so that is at least one good reason to call Free instead of Destroy. Even if the structure of you code dictates otherwise, an object might be nil.

Comment: Thankyou for all the replies. I see now that the destructor is unnecessary, however I only implemented it because I was clutching at straws to try and fix the original Thread problem. With or without the destructor, the Threads continue to persist, any insight on that problem?

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer this question, it only simplifies the problem to be simulated.

See how many threads is running after each button click. It uses the [`Simple Google Maps example`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html), so the problem is not even in your javascript part.

*Unit1 - contains main form, where is just a button with OnClick event handler*

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, PsAPI, TlHelp32, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetThreadCount(const APID: Cardinal): Integer;
var
  NextProc: Boolean;
  ProcHandle: THandle;
  ThreadEntry: TThreadEntry32;
begin
  Result := 0;
  ProcHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
  if (ProcHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
  try
    ThreadEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(ThreadEntry);
    NextProc := Thread32First(ProcHandle, ThreadEntry);
    while NextProc do
    begin
      if ThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID = APID then
      Inc(Result);
      NextProc := Thread32Next(ProcHandle, ThreadEntry);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(ProcHandle);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ModalForm: TForm2;
begin
  ModalForm := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    ModalForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    ModalForm.Free;
  end;
  ShowMessage('Thread count: ' + 
    IntToStr(GetThreadCount(GetCurrentProcessId)));
end;

end.
```

*Unit2 - contains form with the TWebBrowser on it and the form's OnCreate event handler*

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, ActiveX;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  HTMLString: AnsiString =
    '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
    '<html>' +
    '  <head>' +
    '    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>' +
    '    <meta name="viewport"' +
    '        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">' +
    '    <meta charset="UTF-8">' +
    '    <style type="text/css">' +
    '      html, body, #map_canvas {' +
    '        margin: 0;' +
    '        padding: 0;' +
    '        height: 100%;' +
    '      }' +
    '    </style>' +
    '    <script type="text/javascript"' +
    '        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>' +
    '    <script type="text/javascript">' +
    '      var map;' +
    '      function initialize() {' +
    '        var myOptions = {' +
    '          zoom: 8,' +
    '          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),' +
    '          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP' +
    '        };' +
    '        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(''map_canvas''),' +
    '            myOptions);' +
    '      }' +
    '      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ''load'', initialize);' +
    '    </script>' +
    '  </head>' +
    '  <body>' +
    '    <div id="map_canvas"></div>' +
    '  </body>' +
    '</html>';

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTMLStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
  if Assigned(WebBrowser1.Document) then
  begin
    HTMLStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      HTMLStream.WriteBuffer(Pointer(HTMLString)^, Length(HTMLString));
      HTMLStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      (WebBrowser1.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(HTMLStream));
    finally
      HTMLStream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: The problem is GoogleMaps's site related or in any page loaded the TWebBrowser leaks?

Comment: @EMBarbosa, it happens for some pages, but not for all. So it's not only GoogleMaps related.